# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I get this in the yellow box:

> **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): ReferenceError: firebase is not defined ReferenceError: firebase is not defined**

How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import FBSDK, { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

import { firebaseRef } from '/home/mayura/AndroidProject/NiceTry/app/services/Firebase.js';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Facebook extends Component {
  _fbAuth() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('Login was cancelled');
        } else {
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (AccessTokenData) => {
              const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
                AccessTokenData.accessToken
              );
              firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                .then(
                  (result) => {
                    // promise succesful
                    console.log(error.code);
                    console.log(error.message);
                  },
                  (error) => {
                    //promise rejected

                    console.log(error);
                  }
                );
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log('Some error occured: ' + error);
            }
          );
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fbAuth}>
          <Text>Login with Facebook</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages or code (or other textual content). Instead post the actual error message and code, so that we can search for it, copy paste it, etc. You can do so now by clicking the edit link under your question.

Comment: Hey, sorry for posting pictures. I've edited the question. Hope that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It says `firebase is not defined`. Check if you have correctly installed and imported firebase lib to your component

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey I checked firebase is installed and I have also imported it in my component.

Comment: Check the caps, you import as Firebase but then use firebase